# Are gnome-session-fallback and metacity + gnome-panel the same?a

Tags: gnome-panel, metacity, gnome-session-fallback

Are installing gnome-session-fallback and installing metacity and gnome-panel the same? To me, they seem to both install metacity and gnome 2? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you should install gnome-session-flashback. gnome-session-fallback is just a transitional package to ease upgrade to gnome-session-flashback.